# Switch distinct values in a column into column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new table by using the dataset in the link below. The return I want to have is like the picture below. Could someone please help?

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/766e3/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Employeeid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BusinessUniteID = 1 then Scores END) as score_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BusinessUniteID = 2 then Scores END) as score_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BusinessUniteID = 3 then Scores END) as score_3
FROM t_d
GROUP BY EmployeeId;
```

This assumes that you know what all the business unit ids are.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/766e3/4) is a db<>fiddle.